# C++: XOR between string and int

Tags: c++

Say I have two vectors:

```
std::vector<int> numbers;
std::vector<std::string> words;
```

I read two files: one that has only numbers in it and the other one has words. I want to use numbers as a cypher for my words thus `numbers` `XOR` `words` would be a `ciphertext` and `ciphertext` `XOR` `numbers` would give me `words` back.

I'm trying to do something like

```
int charCount = wordsCount >= numbersCount ? numbersCount : wordsCount;

for (int i = 0; i < charCount; i++) {
    result[i] = words[i] ^ numbers[i];
}
```

But that doesn't work

```
no match for 'operator^' (operand types are '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::value_type' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} and '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<int>, int>::value_type' {aka 'int'})|
```

How can I do it the most simplest way?

UPD: So what I really want is XOR every character in my word with following number.

Comment: What does it mean to XOR `"hello"`, and `42`?

Comment: You probably want to apply the XOR to every _character_ not every _word_?

Comment: @churill thats right, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to xor all the characters of a word, with the corresponding number, you need to iterate over each char. There's no way of xor-ing all the characters of a string with `operator^`.

You could do this

```
std::transform(std::begin(numbers), 
               std::begin(numbers) + std::min(numbers.size(), words.size()),
               std::begin(words),
               std::begin(words),
               [](auto number, auto word)
               {
                  std::transform(std::begin(word), std::end(word), 
                                 std::begin(word), 
                                 [number](auto c)
                                 { return c ^ number; });
                  return word;
               });
```

Which is symmetric, so can be used for encoding and decoding.

I rarely suggest this, but maybe the conventional for-loop is more readable in this case:

```
int min = std::min(numbers.size(), words.size());

for (int i = 0; i < min; ++i) 
  for (int j = 0; j < words[i].size(); ++j)
    words[i][j] = words[i][j] ^ numbers[i];
```

Comment: ADL is evil. Avoid using it unless strictly required.

Comment: @alterigel I've been badly bitten by that, so I avoid it as far as possible.

Comment: @cigien That seems to work, thank you. A rather stupid question but what type is words[i][j] so I can save it and use it later?

Comment: A `string` is composed of `char`s.

Comment: @joeyb4 If the answer works for you, consider accepting it.